# How to change screen dpi in elementary Freya?

Tags: display, resolution

I have 1440x900 pixels (411x263 millimeters or 16.14173x10.11811 inches approximately) monitor and my resolution according to `xdpyinfo` is 89X87 dots per inch. But it should be 89.2x88.94 isn't it? Do I need to bother about changing DPI slightly to 89x89 (maybe to another value 89x88) or not? If so how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot easily change the DPI in elementary OS or any other Gnome based environment.

You basically only have easy control over resolution and scaling factor.

You can try to calculate and set the optimal DPI by following [this answer for setting DPI in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi), but I would not recommend it. The actually numbers you see might not exactly match due to rounding or misreporting.

In my opinion it is better not to get hung up on the numbers, ask yourself whether it looks good to you. Elementary OS already handles high DPI screens very well by default.

Comment: I'm okay with 89x87 and I bet changing it to 89x89 is almost indistinguishable, but was just curious why elementary gave my slightly inaccurate results.